# How to load node.js/angular 2 project in Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio

I'm following along in a node.js/angular tutorial in which I'm given the following "seed" project:

[image]

I'm told in the tutorial that I can open this in Visual Studio... but how?

Visual Studio requires a project or solution file to open the project. All I see here are some javascript and json files. Sure, I can open individual files, but how do I open the whole project in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

A project in VS Code is just a folder so if you open `seed-project` in VS Code it should auto populate all the files and set you up to do angular.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to load your Angular Project in Visual Studio.

Step 1: Open Visual Studio.

Step 2: Go to File--> New--> Project

Step 3: Choose JAvaScript in other languages and select "From existing Node.js code" as shown in below screen shot.

Step 4: Browse location folder.

Step 5: Click Next Next and Finish
[image]

Comment: I don't have the "Other Languages" option in Visual Studio 2015